# Prevent opening link in new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am using `WrappedJsonResult` as a `return` statement in one of my action methods.

**Note:**
I couldn't upload a complete code as I am working out this in a project.

**My form is something like this:**

```
<form 
      action="/controller/actionmethod" 
      enctype="multipart/form-data" 
      id="excelUploadForm" 
      method="post" 
      name="excelUploadForm" 
      target="FileUploadTarget">

     //some contents inside form
</form>

 <iframe 
        id="FileUploadTarget" 
        name="FileUploadTarget" >
 </iframe>
```

**My code is:**

```
return new WrappedJsonResult
            {
                Data = new
                {
                    isSuccess = true,
                    CusEvent = "close",
                    CusMsg = "File Uploaded Successfully"
                }
            };
```

On successful upload, the above *jsonresult* opens in new tab in `textarea`.

Html generated & ***opened in new tab*** to get the `WrappedJsonResult`is:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
          <textarea id="jsonResult" name="jsonResult"> 

          {
             "isSuccess":true,
             "CusEvent":"close",
             "CusMsg":"File Uploaded Successfully"
          }

          </textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

**My problem:**

Jsonresult opens in new tab. That I want to prevent it.

I cannot simulate where the problem occurs. Whether this occurs due to `iframe` or `WrappedJsonResult` or something else.

What is the problem with this ?.

Comment: you can't _target_ a textarea, only a popup or iframe. if the content-type back from the server is weird, it could trigger a download in that popup/iframe. if the target is invalid, it over-writes the current page. if that doesn't appear to be happening, that's because its the weird mime that triggers a download instead of drawing new HTML.

Comment: Is there any way to rectify it?

Comment: Are you using Internet Explorer?   IE doesn't recognise json.   Does it do the same in a proper browser?

Comment: Nope. I'm not using IE. I'm using chrome browser